# Bold characters inside of a word with Markdown

Tags: markdown

I am using GitHub's markdown, and I would like to emphasize the initials of an abbreviation within a few words. Majuscules are not an option, so I want to use bold text.

I have tried:

```
**G**esellschaft **m**it **b**eschränkter **H**aftung
```

Which outputs: **G**esellschaft **m**it **b**eschränkter **H**aftung

and:

```
**G** esellschaft **m** it **b** eschränkter **H** aftung
```

Which outputs: **G** esellschaft **m** it **b** eschränkter **H** aftung

How do I get my bold text and steer clear of those spaces?

Comment: The problem seems to the same at [stackexchange flavoured markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140706/how-do-i-make-part-of-a-word-bold-using-markdown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use html:

```
<b>G</b>esellschaft <b>m</b>it <b>b</b>eschränkter <b>H</b>aftung
```

Result:

**G**esellschaft **m**it **b**eschränkter **H**aftung

Comment: According to Markdown: Dingus http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus, what you wrote in the original post should parse as you expect. It seems that both SO and GitHub parse it differently